# AWS CDK is keeping ask me to update the IAM role even if I have already setup the permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am using CDK to deploy my web service, the Docker image has been push to ECR
then I use CDK deploy application to ECS with Fargate tasks

but when I deploy the CDK script, it is keeping ask me to allow it update my IAM role

#### IAM Statement Changes

- ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
- ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
- ecr:BatchGetImage
- ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer

I don't think it's a good idea to allow CI runner have the permission to update IAM resource
so I manually update it. But CDK still ask me to allow it.

Does that means I cannot avoid CDK to update my IAM role?

I try to trace the source code, but I am not familiar with TS.
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/0f0e2055cab08551bc6e5dfb8a1b6219368263c5/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-ecr/lib/repository.ts#L361

### update on 2019/12/31

After consult with AWS community, I got another solution.
If you don't want to allow CI server ask for updating your IAM policies,
you should use `aws_ecs.ContainerImage.from_registry()`
instead of `aws_ecs.ContainerImage.from_ecr_repository()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDK still asks you to update the IAM Role since CDK creates a cloudformation template behind the scenes. This cloudformation template needs permissions in order to create your CDK stack, in your case ECR. The CDK flag changes that involve IAM and ask you for confirmation before proceeding. Therefore, this is the minimal permissions the CDK needs in order to create the stack.

So, no, this means you cannot avoid CDK to update your IAM role.

In order to add policies to this IAM role, use [`.addToPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.Role.html#add-to-policystatement)

> These policies will be created with the role, whereas those added by
>   `addToPolicy` are added using a separate CloudFormation resource
>   (allowing a way around circular dependencies that could otherwise be
>   introduced).

[Example usage:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/permissions.html)

```
role.addToPolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
  effect: iam.Effect.DENY,
  resources: [bucket.bucketArn, otherRole.roleArn],
  actions: ['ec2:SomeAction', 's3:AnotherAction'],
  conditions: {StringEquals: {
    'ec2:AuthorizedService': 'codebuild.amazonaws.com',
}}}));
```

Comment: Sure, Glad i could help :)

Comment: you saved me lots of time!